# Unusual black squares in transparency effect after wake from sleep

Tags: unity, graphics, transparency

I've encountered unusual black squares in semi transparent textures for a while now, usually in processes that were resumed after the computer woke from sleep. For example I've seen the effect in the Battle.net launcher by Blizzard frequently, on different machines. 
But now I often encounter the effect in Unity in Play mode if I let the computer go to sleep. Restarting the scene fixes the display problem.

My 2 questions are:

1. What is that effect?
2. What do I need to do to prevent the effect from reaching my users?

[image]

In this screenshot there are 3 semi transparent particle effects on top of one semi transparent billboard, and at the bottom we see a part of an opaque sphere. The black squares seem to only affect a single one of the particle effects, and disappear if the effect is disabled, and reappear if it's re-enabled.

And here is the same effect in the Blizzard launcher:

[image]

Comment: It's possible that this issue is specific to your graphics card if you are seeing it in games that aren't yours. You shouldn't have to worry too much about it reaching your users.

Comment: @Hi Aidan, I have a friend who has the same issue in some 3rd party applications. We're both using Nvidia cards 2 generations apart. If I don't get any answers I will assume the problem isn't that common, which will provide ease of mind.

Comment: I have never seen this effect, so I'm guessing that it is some sort of weird buffer optimization that NVIDIA uses on some of their cards.